# A question related to study of functions in Prime polynomial theorem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I am studying prime polynomial theorem from notes of a friend and I am unable to prove  a lemma.

Let $F_{q}[t]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F_q$ . Also, let $\pi_{q}(n) $ be the number of monic irreducible $P \in F_q[x] $ of degree $n$.

Let von Mangoldt function be defined as $\Lambda (f) =\deg P$ , if $ f= cP^k $ is a power of a prime $P$ and $0$ otherwise.

Also, define $\psi(n) = \sum_{\substack{\deg f=n\\f\text{ monic}}} \Lambda(f) $.

Prove that $\psi(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} d \pi_{q} (d) $ .

Only $f = P^k$ case need to be dealt due to nature of Mangoldt function.

LHS :$\psi(n) = \sum_{\substack{\deg f =n\\f\text{ monic}}} \deg P = \sum_{\deg f=n} n/k$  but I am not able to simplify after it.

RHS:
$\sum_{d| n} d \pi_{q} (d) = \sum_{d|n} d$ .

I am not able to proceed further despite thinking a lot.

Can you please help.

Comment: $\pi_q(d)\neq 1$ in general, and for LHS note the degree of $P$ divides $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are perhaps overthinking it.
\begin{equation}
\psi (n) = \sum_{\deg f = n, f \text{ monic}} \Lambda(f) = \sum_{\deg f = n, f = P^k, P \text{ monic irreducible}} \deg(P)
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
\psi (n) = \sum_{P \text{ monic irreducible}, \deg(P)|n} \deg(P) = \sum_{d|n} \# \{ P \text{ monic irreducible} | \deg(P) = d\} * d = \sum_{d|n} d \pi_q(d)
\end{equation}

Comment: Will have a look at it later. Awarding you the bounty.

Comment: How did you wrote that $\phi(n) $in the rightmost of 1st line is equal to $\sum_{ P monic irreducible , deg(P)|n} deg(P)$?

Comment: You have $deg(f) = n$ and $f = P^k$. That tells you that $k * deg(P) = n$, and specifically that $deg(P) | n$.  I'm not sure which part you're having difficulty with, could you elaborate?